# JBoss wildfly 10 NoClassDefFoundError at migrate from JBoss 4.2

Tags: java, module, addition, wildfly, jericho-html-parser

I have a spring mvc application running into JBoss 4.2. I'm trying migrate this web app to JBoss wildfly 10 (wildfly-10.0.0.Final version).

When I try deploy my app show this error:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"myApp.war\\\".POST_MODULE\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"myApp.war\\\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \\\"myApp.war\\\"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class org.ajaxtags.tags.AjaxDisplayTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \\\"deployment.myApp.war:main\\\" from Service Module Loader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/id/jericho/lib/html/Segment
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.id.jericho.lib.html.Segment from [Module \\\"deployment.myApp.war:main\\\" from Service Module Loader]\"}}"
```

Looking for the web, I read that I need to load the jar "jericho-html-2.6.1.jar". To do it, I added in ${wildfly_home}/modules/system/layers/base/au/id/jericho/lib/html/main
 the jericho-html-2.6.1.jar and this module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="au.id.jericho.lib.html">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jericho-html-2.6.1.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I added the extension in standalone.xml

```
<extension module="au.id.jericho.lib.html"/>
```

But I get same error.

Comment: Think you should use `jericho-html-2.6.1.jar`. without `-sources`.

Comment: Hi @Jens, I tried it but don´t work. How do I validate that the jericho module is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you add the extension in standalone.xml ??
You should add a WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to your war with :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="au.id.jericho.lib.html" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I think that I needed add the extension in standalone.xml. 
I understand that what you say is the same as adding the library in the file pom. I was trying to deploy the application without touching my war.

Comment: You can do this using overlays : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Overlays which is a way to add/replace a file in a war without actually modifying it